# Process data from service in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have created a PHP service in Flex Mobile and binded the result with a List. I want to sort the records from the service based on some calculation on data fields. So, is it possible to perform operations on the resultset from the PHP service ?

Detailed question:

I have created the php service through the built in tool in Flash Builder 4.6. I also had bind the service with a List in my view. (Again using GUI controls). Now I want to rearrange the items in the list based on distance from the current location and coordinates from the rows returned by the service. So the approach I was thinking was to, get the content from the service. Extract lat,lon and calculate the distance. Then update the list again.

I tried the following line in a function:

```
getAllplacesResult.lastResult[1].lon // lon is a column in the table.
```

But it returns a blank. Is their a more sane or easier way to do this ?

Comment: Yes (there's not much more I can say really, given the information you provide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way is to assign it on an Arraycollection and manipulate data from there.

```
 <mx:ArrayCollection id="myAC" source="{ArrayUtil.toArray(myRO.getAllplacesResult.lastResult)}" />
```

Make sure you bind myAC to your List.

Sort it the way you want to:

```
var collection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
var s:Sort = new Sort();
s.fields = [new SortField("lat"), new SortField("lon")];
s.compareFunction = myCompareFunction;
collection.sort = s;
collection.refresh();

private function myCompareFunction(a:Object, b:Object, fields:Array = null):int {
...
}
```

Also, AS3 is 0 based index. 1 will actually give you the second row (or throw out of range exception)

Comment: I tried this code and tried printing the length of myAC. The length comes as 0.